# Java sockets, everything written stays in memory

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I am sending images through sockets using ByteArrayOutputStreams like this.

```
ImageIO.write(image, "gif", byteArrayO);
       byte [] byteArray = byteArrayO.toByteArray();
       Connection.pw.println("" + byteArray.length);
       int old = Connection.client.getSendBufferSize();
       Connection.client.setSendBufferSize(byteArray.length);
       Connection.client.getOutputStream().write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Everything works OK, the image is like 130kb in the end, and I receive it like this

```
int nbrToRead = Integer.parseInt(slave.input.readLine().trim());
            int old = slave.socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
            slave.socket.setReceiveBufferSize(nbrToRead);
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[nbrToRead];
            int nbrRd = 0;
            int nbrLeftToRead = nbrToRead;
            while (nbrLeftToRead > 0) {
                int rd = slave.socket.getInputStream().read(byteArray, nbrRd, nbrLeftToRead);
                if (rd < 0)
                    break;
                nbrRd += rd; 
                nbrLeftToRead -= rd;
            }

            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayI = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(byteArrayI);
```

It works well, but every image sent the memory heap of java increases like 50 mb. I have tried setting the receivebuffersize, but it still stays up. It goes to maximum in heap, then stays for a while then stops.

How can I clear the buffer so when it has received the bytes it will dispose of them?

Comment: On which side does it leak, client or server?

Comment: Connection is the class which holds client  whish is socket.

Comment: When you create `BufferedImage`s you have to call `flush()`s on those too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java writing to ByteArrayOutputStream memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970742/java-writing-to-bytearrayoutputstream-memory-leak)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things spring to mind:

- You may be holding on to a reference to an object and it's not cleaned up by garbage collection. If the class that is doing the work is a singleton, this is a very common problem.
- Make sure you call close() on any IO classes that you are using (like the BufferedInputSteam).

Comment: `flush()`s are more important than `close()`s.

Comment: ByteArrayInputStream doesn't have a flush() method. ETA : but flush() may be useful for the sender ... not enough info on that code snippet to see.

Comment: I am so sorry! I am testing closing it now, i thought it was gonna close the connection, but it just closes the local instance of bytearrayoutputstream.

Comment: It leaks on the side that sends the image. not the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your object is dereferenced once you've sent it, as remaining references would keep your image in memory. You can do that by setting all instances of that object to `null`.

Additionally, calling `flush()` and `close()` when you're done can greatly help your memory usage.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us all your method, but you've may have the large-memory local variables in scope while waiting for the next image.

Try this:

```
// after you've finished with the input, dereference the memory-heavy objects...
byteArray = null;
byteArrayI = null;
```

Also, you can "nudge" the JVM to garbage collect (you can't *make* it garbage collect) by calling `System.gc()` and yielding the thread. If nulling alone doesn't work, try adding this

```
System.gc(); // "suggest" garbage collection to execute
Thread.yield(); // I have seen this encourage garbage collection to execute
```

Comment: Now I know what the problem is. Almost exactly. Not sure if I should make a new question, so: When I create new instance of bytearrayoutputstream and writes image there using ImageIO.write it first goes up 100 mb in memory, then slowly increasing and after a few times it kinda stops work. Yes, I flush, reset and then close it.

Comment: Yes. You must `close()` on the sending side, otherwise it won't complete the send. Note that `close()` automatically does a `flush()` too, so no need to also call `flush()`.

Comment: Nope. I write everything to this bytestream and then write it "normally" over socket. Thats not a problem. Works fine. But it is when I do ImageIO.write to it the memory increases. It wont disappear when I stop using the stream or close it

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that `Connection` holds an `ObjectOutputStream`. If that's true, then you need to call `reset()` on that stream.

Comment: No, I use socket.getOutputStream() and socket.getInputStream()

Answer (score 0):

I commented but making it as an answer too.

When you create in-memory `BufferedImage`s, you have to call `flush()` on them when you done with them.
I am strongly suspicious your memory leak came from that.

And, as Malached said, make sure everything(BufferedImages, I/O references, and so on) not be left with any kind of references for `gc` works for them.

`System.gc()` is not a solution if the situation is not that your physical memory is really smaller than your `memory-leak-free` program so you have to try it before the `gc` works by himself.